# SOLR: copy 2 fields into another field and add filters to that new field

Tags: solr

While importing I have below fields in CSV file

```
<field name="Brand" type="string" indexed="true"/>
<field name="Colour" type="lowercaseExactMatch"/>
<field name="Keywords" type="text_general"/>
<field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
<field name="Price" type="string" indexed="true"/>
<field name="SKU" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

I want to create another field dynamically `NameKeywords`, in which I want to concat Name and Keywords fields.

Also, I want to apply lowercase, EnglishPorterFilterFactory, EnglishPossessiveFilter, and HyphenatedWordsFilter

So I can apply filters to that field by creating a custom field type. But How to combine two fields into another field?

I saw CopyField into my schema.xml

```
  <copyField source="Name" dest="Name_str" maxChars="256"/>
```

But not sure is it displays anywhere and how to combine fields here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a field named NameKeywords as below.

```
<field name="NameKeywords" type="customFieldType" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

then copy the source fields to destination field as below.

```
<copyField source="Name" dest="NameKeywords"/>
<copyField source="Keywords" dest="NameKeywords"/>
```

Comment: hello abhijit.. I tried with your previous answer of copyfields.. it works..
But you change your answer so I'm trying this chain method.. :)

Comment: Let me know which suits to your requirement :)

Comment: I tried this solution from this url "https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/01/31/concatenating-fields-with-apache-solr", but it did not work.

Comment: Copy fields is easy but as a developer which method you will suggest ? because I want to search on this field only.

Comment: how about the second approach...where you can create a copyfield and index it